# Difference between @BeforeAll & @BeforeSuite

Tags: java, automation, appium-android, appium-java

What is the difference between `@BeforeAll` (io.cucumber.java.BeforeAll) &

```
@BeforeSuite
```

(org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite) annotations?

When using @BeforeSuite , a step inside the method throws null where when using @BeforeAll it doesn't fails.

Comment: Do you want to know the difference between `@BeforeAll` and `@BeforeSuite` or why your code is failing?

If its the latter, you will need to share some of the code and a stacktrace or logs showing the failure.

Comment: I would like to know both. Code part let me share.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between @BeforeAll from io.cucumber.java.BeforeAll and @BeforeSuite from org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite lies in its functionality and the testing frameworks it belongs to. Let's break down the differences:

Purpose:

@BeforeAll from io.cucumber.java.BeforeAll: This annotation is used in Cucumber, a BDD testing framework. It marks a method to run once before all scenarios in a feature file.
@BeforeSuite from org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite: This annotation is part of TestNG, a testing framework designed for testing Java applications. It marks a method to execute once before all tests in a suite.
Scope:

@BeforeAll: It applies to Cucumber scenarios, which are typically written in feature files and implemented using step definitions. The method annotated with @BeforeAll in Cucumber runs before any scenarios in the feature file.
@BeforeSuite: It applies to TestNG test suites, which can contain multiple test classes. The method annotated with @BeforeSuite runs once before any tests in the suite, including all test classes within that suite.
Execution Context:

It's important to note that Cucumber scenarios and TestNG suites operate within different execution contexts. In Cucumber, scenarios are typically run sequentially within a single execution, whereas TestNG suites can execute multiple test classes concurrently or sequentially, depending on the configuration.

Regarding the issue you mentioned where using @BeforeSuite results in a ***null pointer exception*** while using @BeforeAll does not, there could be several reasons for this behavior:

Comment: So - is that both these annotations run before everything during test execution? I don't really get the difference.

Comment: use more markdown formatting